# Object Factories with variadic templates and parameter packing

Tags: templates, vector, c++17

I am trying to create a factory that can store a string as key and a lambda function that finds the appropriate constructor and pass the input arguments to it.
The reason is that, I serialize objects to a file with their class name. Than from class name string I want to find the associated constructor with right parameter count. So I try to generalize this with templates, variadics etc ...

Here is a sample code that demonstrates my needs. But unfortunately it doesn't work yet.

```
#include <any>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base
{
 public:
  virtual void foo() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
 public:
  Derived(std::string a, int b, double c)
  {
    std::cout << "Derived constructor with a " << a << " b " << b << " c " << c << std::endl;
  }
};

class AnotherDerived : public Base
{
 public:
  AnotherDerived(std::string a, int b, double c, std::string d, int e)
  {
    std::cout << "Derived constructor with a " << a << " b " << b << "c " << c << " d " << d << " e " << e << std::endl;
  }
};

// Type-erased factory function
using FactoryFunction = std::function<Base*(const std::vector<std::any>&)>;

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
Base* createObjectHelper(const std::vector<std::any>& args, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
  return new T(std::any_cast<typename std::tuple_element<Is, decltype(args)>::type>(args[Is])...);
}

// Define a factory function for each derived type with variadic arguments
template <typename T>
Base* createObject(const std::vector<std::any>& args)
{
  // FAILS TO COMPILE
  // error C3546: '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand
  // Unpack and forward arguments to the constructor
  return createObjectHelper<T>(args, std::index_sequence_for<decltype(args)...>());
}

int main()
{
  // Create a map of type_info to factory functions
  std::map<std::string, FactoryFunction> factories;

  // Register factory functions for each derived type using lambda functions
  factories["Derived"]        = [](const std::vector<std::any>& args) { return createObject<Derived>(args); };
  factories["AnotherDerived"] = [](const std::vector<std::any>& args) { return createObject<AnotherDerived>(args); };

  // Create an instance of Derived with arguments
  std::vector<std::any> derivedArgs        = {"Alice", 42, 3.14};
  Base* ptr                                = factories["Derived"](derivedArgs);

  // Use the factory function to create a new object based on the type with any number and combination of arguments
  std::vector<std::any> anotherDerivedArgs = {"Charlie", 30, 2.71, "David", 2};
  Base* newPtr                             = factories["AnotherDerived"](anotherDerivedArgs);

  delete ptr;
  delete newPtr;

  return 0;
}
```

Here in the code the compiler fails in the line with given error `return createObjectHelper<T>(args, std::index_sequence_for<decltype(args)...>()); //  error C3546: '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand` I can't fix it.

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ isn't a great description of the problem. Please ask one specific question and make it clear what  the problem that you can't solve is.

Comment: There is a line in the code marked with the error string ( stays right side of the code so its not visible unless you scroll right) which exlpains the problem. ``return createObjectHelper<T>(args, std::index_sequence_for<decltype(args)...>()); //  error C3546: '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand``  I can't fix the error. I have updated the question for clarification.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to convert a `vector<any>` to a parameter pack. I don't think you can do it in a one-liner (or possibly at all).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It can be done, but it's not pretty :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well you can convert it to a parameter pack of `any` but that's not quite what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It's not? _"`return createObjectHelper<T>(args, std::index_sequence_for<decltype(args)...>()); //  error C3546: '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand` I can't fix it."_ looks like that's what's being tried to me.

Comment: @TedLyngmo OP is trying to make a call where both the number of parameters and their types magically travel back in time from run-time to compile-time. The number of parameters part is giving them compilation errors, so OP is asking for help with the number of parameters part. The types part does not give them compilation errors yet simply because it is not instantiated.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, that seems correct. Oh well, one problem at a time. I'm assuming there will be a follow up question for how to solve the next problem now that I've showed how to solve the problem OP asked about.

Comment: You presumably already have serialization in place. Why not build deserialization on the same principles and the same infrastructure? That's what all existing serialization libraries I know of are doing. None are trying to exploit normal constructors.

Comment: Serialization writes the class names to a file. Deserializer reads the class name and constructs the object. That requires to do a switch case, ` `if type is A : return new A()`` instead of this, I register constructor functions and send the class name to the factory. It fetches the right constructor and creates the object. Now I want to pass constructor arguments but it misirably fails. The problem is how I try to register the constructor functions. Simply I want to achive this ``unoredered_map<string, std::function<T*(auto&&...args)>> constructorMap;``

Comment: The requirement for keeping constructors in a factory is this, first I am developing a library and it should be able to expanded by other modules. This means that, if I have a fixed deserializer, it will enconter new types and they will be unknown. Registering new types at runtime is crucial for that. Secondly, some modules may want to override default types in the library, I achive this by registering a new constructor with the same key. ``constructormap["oldClass"] =  []() { new newClass(); }  I did not wanted to dive into the whole stroy.

Comment: To wrap this all the requirement is ``std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<T*(auto&& ...Args)>> factories; factories["myClass"] = [](auto&& ...args) { return new myClass(args); };`` This logic should work but I can't make it :(

Comment: It won't work. Other serialisation libraries exist, look at how they are implemented. Or just use one of them.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make an `index_sequence` with the same size as the `vector` you'd need to add some checks:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N = 0>
Base* createObject(const std::vector<std::any>& args) { 
    // Unpack and forward arguments to the constructor
    if constexpr (N > 5) return nullptr; // max 5 arguments supported
    else {
        if (args.size() > N + 4) return createObject<T, N + 5>(args);
        if (args.size() > N + 2) return createObject<T, N + 3>(args);
        if (args.size() > N + 1) return createObject<T, N + 2>(args);
        if (args.size() > N) return createObject<T, N + 1>(args);

        // args.size() == N:
        return createObjectHelper<T>(args, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    }
}
```

There are other problems with your program, like `Base` missing a `virtual` destructor and `createObjectHelper` can't possibly work like you've defined it, but the above takes care of the problem you asked about.

`createObjectHelper` would need to rebuild the parameter pack of argument types and it could look like this:

```cpp
template <class T, class... Args, std::size_t... Is>
T* createObjectHelper(const std::vector<std::any>& args,
                      std::index_sequence<Is...> is)
{
    constexpr std::size_t I = sizeof...(Args);

    if constexpr (I == sizeof...(Is)) {
        // Args... ready, now check if this a valid combination of arguments
        if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>) {
            return new T(std::any_cast<Args>(args[Is])...);
        } else {
            return nullptr; // invalid combination of arguments
        }
    } else {
        // build Args... from types you support
        if (args[I].type() == typeid(const char*))
            return createObjectHelper<T, Args..., const char*>(args, is);
        else if (args[I].type() == typeid(int))
            return createObjectHelper<T, Args..., int>(args, is);
        else if (args[I].type() == typeid(double))
            return createObjectHelper<T, Args..., double>(args, is);
        else if(args[I].type() == typeid(std::string))
            return createObjectHelper<T, Args..., std::string>(args, is);

        return nullptr; // unsupported type
    }
}
```

Instead of returning `nullptr` you may want to `throw` an exception.

Note that this will instantiate *a lot* of functions. There will be one for each possible combination of the supported arguments. Compilation will take a very long time and this demo will likely timeout before showing any results so you need to compile it offline to see that it works.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EEohe95jb)

You can also inspect the instantiations of all the functions at [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/da32cb1d).

Comment: "`createObjectHelper` can't possibly work" a very apt observation.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Well, it's not the part OP is asking about and I was going back and forth thinking about if I should mention any of the other problems at all. Perhaps I should just remove that section of the answer?

Comment: "Well, it's not the part OP is asking about" I presume OP is not asking about the really hard (impossible) part because there are no compilation errors in that part *yet*.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Most probably, yes. I think it may be doable though... Need to sleep on it a bit :-)

Comment: If there are N parameters and K possible parameter types, you seem to need K^N instantiations of the object creation template. It can be avoided if you manually specify a tuple of argument types for each constructor.

Comment: Manually providing all possible constructors will do the trick ( I have a working version with expilicitly registered constructors. ) but I don't want to do that. To be honest chatgpt help me alot to come this far. I am not good with templates :( But I start thinking that its not possible to do it without explicitly registering all constructor combinations.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, there will be a huge amount of instantiations. I added an implementation of `createObjectHelper` that does that.

Comment: @Cihan It's possible, but you'll have to check every type that you aim to support inside `createObjectHelper` and you need to set a hard limit for the maximum number of arguments like I showed in the answer.

Comment: @Cihan Did you have a chance to verify that my suggestion does what you asked for?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have tested it, thank you for the effort. Its too limiting, I don't want to declare all the input types at first. I need complate freedom. So I have decoupled the object creation from object initialization. With a simple constructor I create the object and I used my construction function for argument passing. This way I can create all the registered objects and call the overriden construction functions the way I want. This version looked to me simple and accomodates all the requirements.

Comment: @Cihan You're welcome! It was a fun exercise :-) Regarding complete freedom: I would, as n.m.couldbeanAI suggested in a comment, look at how others usually do serializing. You need to put the list of the supported types _somewhere_. There's no escaping that. That means creating serializing support for the most fundamental types you aim to support, then builing serializing support for more complex types using the serializing support for the fundamental types and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I need to add my solution here. I have put together a factory that accomodate the fallowing requirements.

- Factory should be able to map the class name to constructor functions. When a class name is given, it should be able to construct the associated object.
- New class constructors should be able to register to the factory during runtime.
- A class should be able to overriden by another class at runtime.
- Factory should be able to create the objects with a constructor (constructor-like function) that takes construction parameters.
- Factory should be able to construct unregistered objects aswell as registered objects.

Here is the implementation of the factory class that meets all the requirements. It may seems weird at first the way I implemented this but this factory is serving a big framework which can be extended by outside modules. The base class must be able to serve some degree of reflection / automated serialization etc.. for the curious eyes, here is the full frame work [ToolKit](https://github.com/Oyun-Teknolojileri/ToolKit/blob/Engine/ToolKit/TKObject.h)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Class {
    std::string Name;
};

class Base {
    public: Base() {}

    virtual void Constructor() {};
    virtual void Deserialize(void * data) {
        // Here goes the implementation for deserializing the data.
        // Every derived class overrides this to perform deserialization.
    };
};

class Derived: public Base {
    public: using Base::Constructor;
    static Class DerivedCls;

    public: Derived() {}

    static Class * StaticClass() {
        return & DerivedCls;
    }

    virtual void Constructor(std::string a, int b, double c) {
        Base::Constructor();
        std::cout << "Derived constructor with a " << a << " b " << b << "c " << c << " d " << std::endl;
    }
};

Class Derived::DerivedCls = {
    "Derived"
};

class AnotherDerived: public Base {
    public: using Base::Constructor;
    static Class AnotherDerivedCls;

    public: AnotherDerived() {}

    static Class * StaticClass() {
        return & AnotherDerivedCls;
    }

    virtual void Constructor(std::string a, int b, double c, std::string d, int e) {
        Base::Constructor();
        std::cout << "AnotherDerived constructor with a " << a << " b " << b << "c " << c << " d " << d << " e " << e <<
            std::endl;
    };
};

Class AnotherDerived::AnotherDerivedCls = {
    "AnotherDerived"
};

class OverrideDerived: public Derived {
    public: using Base::Constructor;
    static Class OverrideDerivedCls;

    public: OverrideDerived() {};

    static Class * StaticClass() {
        return & OverrideDerivedCls;
    }

    virtual void Constructor(std::string a, int b, double c) {
        Derived::Constructor(a, b, c);
        std::cout << "Created OverrideDerived instead of Derived " << a << " b " << b << "c " << c << " d " << std::endl;
    }
};

Class OverrideDerived::OverrideDerivedCls = {
    "OverrideDerived"
};

struct Dummy {
    Dummy() {};

    Dummy(int x, float y) {}
};

class Factory {
    public:
        // Helper function to identify if class T has a StaticClass function.
        template < typename T >
        struct HasStaticClass {
            // Check if T has a StaticClass function
            template < typename U >
                static constexpr auto Check(U * ) -> decltype( & U::StaticClass, std::true_type {});

            // Fallback for when StaticClass is not found
            template < typename >
                static constexpr std::false_type Check(...);

            // Combine the checks for T and its base classes up to TKObject
            static constexpr bool value = decltype(Check < T > (nullptr))::value;
        };

    // Constructor for creating an object during deserialization.
    Base * ConstructBase(std::string Class) {
        auto constItr = constructorMap.find(Class);
        if (constItr != constructorMap.end()) {
            return constItr -> second();
        }

        assert(false && "Unregistered class.");
        return nullptr;
    }

    // Constructor for creating the object with arguments.
    template < typename T,
    typename...Args >
    T * Construct(Args && ...args) {
        if constexpr(HasStaticClass < T > ::value) {
            // We can't directly create the object from the type T ! It may be overridden to create another object.
            // T* obj = new T();
            Base * obj = ConstructBase(T::StaticClass() -> Name);
            T * casted = static_cast < T * > (obj);
            casted -> Constructor(std::forward < Args > (args)...);
            return casted;
        }
        else {
            return new T(std::forward < Args > (args)...);
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    std::unordered_map < std::string,
    std:: function < Base * () >> constructorMap;
};

int main() {
    Factory fac;
    fac.constructorMap["Derived"] = []() {
        return new Derived();
    };
    fac.constructorMap["AnotherDerived"] = []() {
        return new AnotherDerived();
    };

    // Intentionally create OverrideDerived instead of Derived.
    fac.constructorMap["Derived"] = []() {
        return new OverrideDerived();
    };

    fac.Construct < Derived > ("alpha", 1, 2.2);
    fac.Construct < AnotherDerived > ("alpha", 1, 2.2, "omega", 5);
    fac.Construct < AnotherDerived > ();
    fac.Construct < int > (3);
    fac.Construct < Dummy > ();
    fac.Construct < Dummy > (7, 3.1 f);

    return 0;
```